# mysql Date time query help?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in which I have two fields i.e name of the product and release date (type:date)...

->>I want to select all the products which have not been launched yet!!!

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select product_name
from products
where release_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the current date and time. MySQL will natively compare two dates, so that's a plus. Therefore, all you have to do is grab all of the products with a `release_date` greater than the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
select
    product_name
from
    products
where
    release_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Note that this can be historical, too. So, you could substitute any date for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and get all of the products that hadn't (or had, if you did less than (<)) been released by that date, like so:

```
where
    release_date > '7/1/2009'
```

Read up on the [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more info on how you can manipulate dates to do some really neat queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE release_date > NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE DATEDIFF(`release_date`, CURDATE()) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

also need to include null values

SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE DATEDIFF(`release_date`, CURDATE()) > 1 or 'release_date' is null